# Why does ${$#} return same result as $$ in the shell?

Tags: shell, variable

While trying to get last positional parameter set in `/bin/dash` , I've tried `echo ${$#}`. Surprisingly this did not result in an error, but into PID which is the same as `$$` variable contents. Question, is why did that syntax work ? What is the syntax rule that shell applied here ?

Basically, what I did is

```
$ set 1 2 3 4 5
$ echo ${$#}
13819
$ echo $$
13819
```

Apparently, `%` character also get ignored in such construct

```
$ echo ${$%}
13819
```

But `*` and `@` result in bad substitution error:

```
$ echo ${$*}
sh: 10: Bad substitution
$ echo ${$@}
sh: 11: Bad substitution
```

Comment: What are you expecting `${$*}` and `${$@}` to produce?

Comment: @Kusalananda  No expectations. I was trying other characters beside `#` and `%` and what behavior results from those.

Comment: To actually do indirection in Dash, use `eval`, e.g. `dash -c 'set 1 2 3 4 5; eval "echo \$$#"'`. Source: [Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh#A.24.7B....7D)

Comment: @wjandrea Yep, already aware of that one. There's actually already a question about it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1853946/getting-the-last-argument-passed-to-a-shell-script  I was trying to find a method by myself without reading the question first ( and I already knew `for i; do true; done` to get last item into `$i` ) but was looking for something more elegant. `eval` of course can have potential issues, thought to what extent - that's another topic.  But yes, it's an option

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This is `$$` [with an empty prefix removed](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02):

> `${parameter#[word]}`
>
> **Remove Smallest Prefix Pattern**. The *word* shall be expanded to produce a pattern. The parameter expansion shall then result in *parameter*, with the smallest portion of the prefix matched by the pattern deleted. If present, *word* shall not begin with an unquoted `#`.

The same applies for `%` (suffix). `@` and `*` are not parameter expansion modifiers, so they are errors. It would happen for `$?`, `$-`, or a hypothetical `$=` as well. `${$+}` is an empty expansion.

Comment: I should have recognized parameter substitution immediately there. Good catch.